# 404 ngx-pagination angular 2

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I get 404  error for ngx-pagination module :  whenever I try to start Angular 2 application,

`/ngx-pagination` is present in node-modules and in package.json.

Can anybody assist? I am using quickstart-master.

Your help will be appreciated.

App.module reference ...

```
import { NgxPaginationModule } from "ngx-pagination";

@NgModule({
 imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, routing, NgxPaginationModule],
 declarations: [ ClientComponent,HeaderComponent],
 bootstrap: [ HeaderComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What URL are you using? And can you add the `routing` that you're importing please?

Comment: I get 404 on start up console ... For ngx-pagination. It's not routing error but package error ... ngx-pagination is not found. (rxjs /notification )

Comment: Can you add the error into your question then please?

Comment: I just amended my question: excuse me please...I don't know if that answered your concern, I really thought I had stated alright on the title. Forgive me please.

Comment: Any chance you can create a StackBlitz that reproduces the error please?

Comment: I am a actually using a phone now, to comment... at home. I ran out of Internet access. May you please try to use the available information?

Comment: The available information is not sufficient to reproduce the problem, so I can't really assist. You've told us what the problem is, but not given enough information for someone to deduce why it's happening

Comment: Yes, however, am saying npm start produce an error 404 error for ngx-pagination... leading to application failing to start...and loading forever.

Comment: @user184994 You may down vote my question but the time will certainly come when it'll be known that I am actual correct ... This is an issue that is coming from the maker of this package/module. This error is above my knowledge or understanding because I did what is expected of me npm start and a 404 error came boom ...!!

Comment: Sorry, Im trying to help, but I cannot reproduce the problem, and therefore cannot give any more info. If you're certain that it is actually a bug from the author of this module, then StackOverflow is not the correct place to raise it. It should be raised with the authors on their GitHub page.

Comment: Does your ngx-pagination load and start up properly on your side ?

Comment: You can just try it on your side and see if it works, for I doubt it'll work on  your side too...

Comment: It works on my side, which is why I'm asking for steps to reproduce the issue

Comment: But 404 means the ulr is wrong ... when you analyse, which URL could be wrong ... ? because the file is present in node modules...?

Comment: DId you add it to your System.js configuration?

Comment: No ... where ? Under map ?

Comment: Yes, if it's not in there it won't be available at runtime.

Comment: Okay ... 'ngx-pagination': ... then; how must I construct the ngx-pagination  bundle in system Js config?

Comment: Because I tried : 'ngx-pagination': 'node_modules/ngx-pagination', ... I still get the same error

Comment: I've added the answer below, try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `systemjs.config.js` file has been updated to load the module at runtime.

Simply add:

```
'ngx-pagination': 'npm:ngx-pagination/dist/ngx-pagination.umd.js'
```

Into the `map` object of that file.

Comment: Awesome man ... I just did. :) ... but you should also bring back my rating by removing the down vote ... because somehow I became the key to your memory by telling you to analyse the URL since 404 means wrong URL. ..Please.  @user184994 in this case system js config mapping URL was the issue...

Comment: Now@user184994 how do I append the currentPage to the http URL ://localhost:8009/clients?page =  & size = 5 ... how do I pass items per page and size tof the URL @user184994 to the rest URL in my service...because the controls are there but they are not pressable

Comment: `let url =  \`http://localhost:8009/clients?page=${pageNum}&size=${pageSize}\` `where pageNum and pageSize are variables. Note that I'm using backticks here and not quotes for the string

Comment: Remember :( pageChange)="page=$event " ... now how do I keep track of changing pages ?and must I use magic quotes ?

Comment: Okay how do I pass page num to the service from html?

Comment: Look man thenough controls are not clickable ...how do I fix this ?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] in Stackblitz or something similar so I can see *why* it's not working?

Comment: Am sorted I for clicks I can navigate through pages but ... Now there is one last problem left;  I have 6 records from from my db... now when I set size to equals 6 it return one record ... how do I make size to return all records @user184994...

Comment: But when I set size to 3 and items per page to 3, it displays 2 rows/two items per page and last one on second page ... omitted other 3 recorda...now how do I get all six records...?and perhaps page 3 times...?

Comment: Oh oops. No need to send page number and or size .... from: java : findAll (Request.of(...)).iterate () ; Angular takes care of everything ... a man is done now!!!